# GWT "database" (client-side)

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I'm looking for something like a database for GWT objects (inside the browser). It must work without HTML5 or Gears (or any browser plugins). It doesn't have to be capable of everything a database can do, but the most important features would be

- **automated indexing**, on multiple columns
- some kind of API or language to perform (a limited subset of) queries

It could be a bit similar to [Taffy DB](http://taffydb.com/), but it **must** have automated indexing, and it *should* provide a GWT API. I hope, it would be even smaller in download size than Taffy, if it re-uses code from the GWT library.

(Maybe I should add, that I don't need permanent storage. It's ok, if the data has to be reloaded/regenerated when the user hits reload.)

Comment: Could you elaborate some more on why you need this? If you just want to save some round trips to the server, ReqeuestFactory from GWT 2.1 should do that for you (AFAIK) - it handles caching, updates, etc.

Comment: @Igor: I have a data model on the client. The model isn't extremely large, but I need to query it very often by different (combinations of) keys. One solution would be to use no indexes at all, and always iterate through all data - which is quite inefficient. Another solution is to create a lot of HashMaps, and keep them all updated manually when the model changes. But what I'd really like to have is a data structure or system that keeps the indexes updated automatically, and lets me query the model by different aspects. BTW, I don't find much info about RequestFactory on the Web.

Comment: I see now (though I don't know how to solve this problem :)). Have you made any benchmarks? IE6 will probably suck as usual, but modern browsers have nowadays highly efficient JS engines. As for RequestFactory (if it's still called that) - it's described in one of GWT's Google IO 2010 sessions, a sample should be in the GWT 2.1 branch in GWT's SVN (bikeshed).

Comment: @chris_I - I had a similar requirement for one of my projects, and I implemented it by using Hashmap's as my indexing mechanism. Made 1 hashmap per column that I wanted to index. It wasn't too difficult to implement, worked fast enough on all browsers and didn't require any libraries. Regarding updating the model, I created it dynamically; not sure why you think it would be maintenance heavy.

Comment: @sri: Good to hear, that you already have this working in your app. It's definitely an option for me, too. I'd prefer a "database" solution, because I believe it would be cleaner, especially when you have non-unique columns, or when performing a join over 3 or more "tables". But if something like that doesn't exist, I'll go on with (or even without) the HashMap indexes.

Comment: I think something like that would also be very slow to implement in pure Javascript. I believe that's why the HTML 5 spec for Web SQL is offloading the work to an embedded SQLite DB.

Comment: Given that Taffy does what you want, I'd suggest writing a GWT wrapper for Taffy using JSNI.

Comment: @tdavies: Unfortunately, Taffy doesn't do everything I need. It's just an example, that goes into the right direction. Especially, it doesn't do automated indexing, which would be the most important feature for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[XBSDB](http://xbsdb.org) seems to be good library for client-side db plus [indexing solution](http://xbsdb.org/theory.html).

Comment: This is absolutely great! I can't believe, I didn't find it (and that it's only on 4th page on Google when searching for javascript database). It's about 32k gzipped JavaScript - I wonder, how much smaller this could be, if it were built on GWT (assuming that many classes like HashMap are already loaded...) But I think, it's a wonderful project!! Thanks for the link.

Comment: :) no problem, just did a quick google search ;). Am I getting the bounty?..lolz, thats a bit greedy.

Comment: @Chris Lercher - Are you using XBSDB?  How is it?

Answer (score 2):

You may take a look at [itemscript](http://code.google.com/p/itemscript/), it has an in memory "database" which you can query using REST-like URL fragments. I haven't tried it but it looks promising. I have to agree with tdavies that if you like Taffy, writing JSNI wrapper around it is quite trivial task.

Some time ago I created simple in-memory database-like system in GWT, where I leveraged existing Comparator interface for sorting, created simple Filter interface, and simple Query used to store any number of Comparators and Filters. Simple generic ModelManager class which stored model objects in one of collection classes and was running my Queries. It worked pretty well even without any support for indexing.

You won't find any existing solutions for your problem, I spent huge amount of time looking for one. Apart of that, why not give HTML5 a try?

Comment: ItemScript is a good idea - a REST API may really be useful. | A homegrown is the most likely solution for me, too. | HTML5: The app must at least run on IE7 (I'm already happy, that I can probably drop IE 6)...

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Dojo's Data Store?

I'm not sure how well it fits your specific needs, but it's a pure JavaScript solution.  Like much of Dojo, the documentation can be a bit difficult to sort through, but there's an article about using Dojo Grid and the basic MVC pattern on developerWorks that may interest you.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-dojogrid/index.html

Cheers.

Comment: I can't find anything about automated indexing, but it looks like a nice library - thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at SQLite? Here's a handy video tutorial...

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DZSZIfhzc3A

Comment: I see now, that my question probably isn't clear on this point: I said "It must work without HTML5 or Gears." - but what I mean with that, is that it should work on all GWT-supported browsers (maybe except the very old ones), without the user installing anything (not even Flash). I'm talking about a pure JavaScript solution (like Taffy).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you reconsider your design, browsers are not the most responsive of applications on a good day for a variety of reasons. In addition to this the design of embedding a database in the browser session (no matter how light) is placing explicit demand on the thin client. The thin client may or may not have the resources to support the requirements.

If you have explicit control over the thin clients (corporate environment?) it would be best to leverage some desktop technologies or applets (java?) outside of the immediate browser context.

Comment: No control over the clients. Anyone can use it, for free (as long as they have JavaScript enabled, but that's required for GWT apps anyway). The performance is not a problem in modern browsers, as long as the model isn't too large, and as long as you use indexes (as has been done by others). In fact, it's a lot faster for users, when the model can be queried locally. Moreover, it saves a lot of bandwidth. The model is strongly interlinked, and can be queried in many ways, so it's really in the best interest for the user. And keeping the model local is IMO the way to go for modern web apps.

Comment: I assume you aren't worried about mobile platforms that may be resource constrained, sounds interesting though so future please feed back how the solution evolves

Answer (score 0):

I have written a small library for doing client side storage in GWT. Its based on local-storage and works on all HTML5 browsers (including the smart phone browsers). It allows you to store data in object stores and databases.

You can check it out here, and see if it meets your needs: https://code.google.com/p/gwt-localstorage-db/